# Why aren't error messages printing correctly when this test fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine

I have this test, and when it fails and prints the variable named `errorMessage`, it prints in a way that seems impossible to me. Here's my code:

```
  function getNamesFromTypescriptFiles(): string[] {
    const items = fs.readdirSync('./tsc/names');
    const filenames = _.filter(items, (fn) => {
      return fn.indexOf('.spec.') === -1;
    });
    const names = _.map(filenames, (fn) =>
      fn.replace('.ts', '')
    );
    return names;
  }


  it('has an array element for each typescript file', () => {
    const names = getNamesFromTypescriptFiles();

    expect(names.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

    for (const name of names) {
      expect(
        (nameArray as ReadonlyArray<string>).includes(
          name
        )
      ).toBe(
        true,
        'The nameArray did not include ' + name
      );
      const path = './story/names/' + name + '-content.twee';
      const exists = fs.existsSync(path);
      expect(exists).toBe(true, `Could not find ${path}`);

      const content = fs.readFileSync(path, { encoding: 'utf8' });

      const passageLines = _.filter(content.split('\n'), (line) => {
        return line.startsWith('::');
      });
      expect(passageLines.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
      for (const passageLine of passageLines) {
        if (!/.*\[.*\].*/.test(passageLine)) {
          const errorMessage =
            name +
            ' has a passage named "' +
            passageLine +
            '" that has no tags. You must at least put an exclude tag.';
          console.log(errorMessage);
          expect(true).toBe(false, errorMessage);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

When this prints, it looks like this:

```
  Message:
" that has no tags. You must at least put an exclude tag.'. Passage name
  Stack:
" that has no tags. You must at least put an exclude tag.'.med ":: Passage name
        at <Jasmine>
```

I cannot figure out how such an error message is possible (it says the same thing in the console.log I have above it): It's as if it's cutting the string and half and rearranging it. How is this possible? It seems as if I have some sort of race condition, but as far as I can tell, this is not running in parallel.

I am using typescript and running the test in Jasmine. For what it's worth, this test always fails appropriately, it's only the message that is wrong.

Comment: The only thing that pops into my head is if you're running on Windows, and it happens to be a weird thing where Windows is using `\r\n` instead of `\n`, and the last character in your passageLine is an `\r` which is causing the rest of your message to be overwritten. Sort of a moonshot (I don't even know whether js and node.js have protections against it), but maybe that's what's happening?

Comment: @Joundill yes I am on Windows so that might be it. What would be a solution if this is the cause?

Comment: Just strip the `\r`s. They're only there to mimic a typewriter anyway.

Comment: @Joundill I fixed it with this line `const passageLines = _.filter(content.split(os.EOL), (line) => {`

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to hear that Windows CRLFs are still a pain in the arse :)